# form is being submitted even if onsubmit function returns false

Tags: javascript, forms

So I have a form that looks like this :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" onSubmit="submitFormButton()">
```

and my submitformbutton function :

```
function submitFormButton(){
    document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').action = '';
    document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').method = 'POST';
    if (showWarning == true){
        var agree = confirm("wtf?");
        if (agree){
            document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById('vacationApplicationForm').submit();
    }
}
```

And when I click cancel in confirm dialog the form is still being submitted. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: What happens if you place `return false;` at the end of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" onSubmit="submitFormButton()">
```

To:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" onSubmit="return submitFormButton()">
```

When using html attributes, you need to use `return` keyword!

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the value in the `onsubmit` attribute. It should be:

```
onsubmit="return submitFormButton();"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the return value of your function when you call it:

```
onSubmit="return submitFormButton()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update form function like below;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" onSubmit="submitFormButton();return false;">
```

Here is a working demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/WnRa2/**